# BOX: Create File Request

Tags: file, request, box

I am working with Box and faced with the need to create a file request via the API. The directory (https://developer.box.com/reference/resources/file-request/) says HOW TO GET INFORMATION ABOUT an EXISTING file_request through its ID, but how to find out this identifier (through a request) or how to create this file request?
I found a bunch of guides on how to create a File Request using the BOX Itself, but I didn't find how to create a file request through the API request.

For example:

POST: .../folder/folder_id/file_request

GET: .../folder/folder_id/file_request

Please help me figure this out. I will be glad of any help. Thank you for reading this.

I found a bunch of guides on how to create a File Request from the Box itself. And I want to do the same functionality (getting a link for further use) in my application through a request.